# System.Drawing DrawLines with Variables

Tags: c#, asp.net, system.drawing

In System.Drawing there is a command called DrawLines.

```
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83k7w0zx(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2
```

I need arrays X and Y to be plotted as a PointF in "Single Format" but with a "F" at the end of each X and Y point.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
double[] X = new double[]{10,15,20,25,30};
double[] Y = new double[]{100,150,200,250,300};
using (Bitmap xPanel = new Bitmap(500, 500))
{
    using (Graphics objGraphicPanel = Graphics.FromImage(xPanel))
    {
            for (int nn = 2; nn <= 5; nn++)
            {
                float x1 = Convert.ToSingle(X[nn - 1]);
                float y1 = Convert.ToSingle(Y[nn - 1]);
                float x2 = Convert.ToSingle(X[nn]);
                float y2 = Convert.ToSingle(Y[nn]);
                PointF[] ptf =
                {
                    new PointF(x1, y1),
                    new PointF(x2, y2)
                };
                objGraphicPanel.DrawLines(colorPen, ptf);
                xPanel.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        }
        string Imgbase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
        MyImage.Src = "data:image/png;base64," + Imgbase64;
        objGraphicPanel.Dispose();
    }
    xPanel.Dispose();
```

This does not work because it must be in the format:

```
                PointF[] ptf =
                {
                    new PointF(10.56F, 25.78654F),
                    new PointF(500.123456F, 234.567F)
                };
```

PointF requires the "float single" format but I also need the "F" at the end of each array point to get the PointF and DrawLines to work.

How do I get that "F" after or the code equivalent?

This is only an example my arrays are much larger.

Answer (score 0):

The place

```
PointF[] ptf =
{
    new PointF(x1, y1),
    new PointF(x2, y2)
};
```

is not a problem. PointF accepts only float arguments. When you put 'F' in the end of the number you just tell the compiller that your number is float (not double). In your code values x1, x2, y1, y2 are already float, because you define them as

```
float x1 = ...
float y1 = ...
```

The problem is, that you iterate your array from 2 to 5. In C# numeration in arrays is from 0 to N-1 (N is length of the array). So you should write

```
for (int nn = 1; nn < 5; nn++)
```

or, and this is better

```
for (int nn = 1; nn < X.Length; nn++)
```

Also you save your image at each iteration. I think

```
xPanel.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

should be outside the cycle for.

Also when you write

```
using (...)
{
    ...
}
```

you don't need to dispose the item you create inside the brackets ( and ). The dispose is called automatically in the end of the using operator.
So the lines

```
objGraphicPanel.Dispose();
```

and

```
xPanel.Dispose();
```

are redundant.

Also, it is not necessary to create array ptf for drawing a single line. You can use DrawLine method:

```
objGraphicPanel.DrawLine(colorPen, x1, y1, x2, y2);
```

So, the folowing code shoud work fine

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
double[] X = new double[]{10,15,20,25,30};
double[] Y = new double[]{100,150,200,250,300};
using (Bitmap xPanel = new Bitmap(500, 500))
{
    using (Graphics objGraphicPanel = Graphics.FromImage(xPanel))
    {
        for (int nn = 1; nn < X.Length; nn++)
        {
            float x1 = Convert.ToSingle(X[nn - 1]);
            float y1 = Convert.ToSingle(Y[nn - 1]);
            float x2 = Convert.ToSingle(X[nn]);
            float y2 = Convert.ToSingle(Y[nn]);
            objGraphicPanel.DrawLine(colorPen, x1, y1, x2, y2);
        }
    }
    xPanel.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
}
```